# Shell script to start qemu with parameter results in 'invalid option'

Tags: bash, shell-script, qemu

I wrote a shell script to start my win 10 VM with qemu.
Running the script result in the message 'invalid option'. I do not understand this as the qemu VM starts properly if I type the command by hand?

This is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

VMkvm="-enable-kvm"
VMboot="-boot menu=on"
VMdisk="/home/john/VMs/win10.qcow2"
VMformat="qcow2"
VMmemory="4G"
VMcores="2"
VMcpu="host,hv_relaxed,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_time"
VMaudio="-audiodev pa,id=snd0 -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-output,audiodev=snd0"
VMusb=""

parameter="${VMkvm} ${VMboot} -drive file=${VMdisk},format=${VMformat} -m ${VMmemory} -smp ${VMcores} -cpu ${VMcpu} ${VMaudio} ${VMusb}"
 
qemu-system-x86_64 ${parameter}
```

This is the result if I execute the script:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -enable-kvm -boot menu=on -drive file=/home/john/VMs/win10.qcow2,format=qcow2 -m 4G -smp 2 -cpu host,hv_relaxed,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_time -audiodev pa,id=snd0 -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-output,audiodev=snd0 : invalid option
```

The funny thing is that if I copy the error message and remove the colon after 'qemu-system-x86_64' my VM starts. I understand this that the actual command and parameter are okay? So there is something wrong how I start qemu in the script with the parameter?
I am puzzled why this doesn't work. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (unwisely) relying on the splitting of unquoted variable `${parameter}` to tokenize the space-separated string into individual arguments.

```
$ str="foo bar"
$ printf '%s\n' $str
foo
bar
```

However, since you set `IFS` to a value that does not include the space character, no such splitting takes place:

```
$ IFS=$'\n\t'
$ printf '%s\n' $str
foo bar
```

It would be better to assemble the arguments in an *array*:

```
parameter=( "${VMkvm}" "${VMboot}" -drive file="${VMdisk},format=${VMformat}" -m "${VMmemory}" -smp "${VMcores}" -cpu "${VMcpu}" "${VMaudio}" "${VMusb}" )
```

then

```
qemu-system-x86_64 "${parameter[@]}"
```

Comment: thank you steeldriver, that solved the problem! I recently thought about how to improve my shell scripts and stumbled over this blog post where someone introduced "strict bash mode" which included the three "set" as well as the modification of "IFS"; I obviously did not fully understand the implication of playing with "IFS"....